# How to find the angle between source object and all other objects falls in the field of view of source object?

Tags: camera, signal-processing, physics, mathematical-expressions, fieldofview

I am working on a project of security development using RFID tags and RFID reader. RFID reader has a field of view of 70 degrees and any tag fall under this area can be detected by reader. I want to know the respective angle between RFID reader and each tag inside the field of view of reader.

Is it going to be same i.e. 70 degree for each tag in the field of view or is it going to be different?. My understanding is the angle will be different for different tags in the space and i am thinking of parallax but seems like this is not the best approach. If anyone can held me solving this problem.

Comment: What is a tag? What geometrical information does it contain?

Comment: I wasn't aware that RFID readers had any angle resolution at all. But if you're asking whether all tags will be off-axis by the same angle, I suspect you don't understand what you're asking us for.